# JavaScript benchmarking code frozen the browser?

Tags: javascript, performance, frameworks, benchmarking

I`m building a page for benchmarking the JavaScript framework code performance. Here is one of the page http://qatrix.com/benchmark/set-css-style

My idea is using a independent iframe to run the code independently so that make it without conflicts. The benchmarking function is run successfully and able to return reasonable results, but the big problem for this benchmarking page is that it will temporarily **frozen** the web browser while code is runing that the mouse cursor is being pointer no matter where is it, and some of mouse hover effects also unavailable.

So, what`s the problem? And how to solve that? I see some of benchmarking website is no this problem, but they are just benchmarking the code under the same page that i think will be with conflicts.

Here is the code of benchmarking runing under the iframe:

```
var benchmark_code = function ()
{
    <?php echo $_GET['code'] ?>
},
benchmark = function(times)
{
    var start = new Date(),
        i, end;
    for( i = 0; i < times; i++) 
    {
        if( i == 0 )
        {
            try {
                benchmark_code.call();
            }
            catch (e)
            {
                return e;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            benchmark_code.call();
        }
    }
    end = new Date(); 
    return end - start;
};
```

And the source code of benchmarking is here (using Qatrix framework):

http://qatrix.com/js/benchmark.js

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is single threaded with the browser UI.  While javascript is executing, all other browser activity is queued up waiting for the javascript thread to finish.  Thus, while your benchmark is running, you won't be able to interact with the page.

If you time each individual loop of your benchmark and sum those times (rather than timing the entire run), you could keep the browser alive by running each loop with a `setTimeout(fn, 0)`.  This would allow the browser to process pending events between each loop of the benchmark.

Here's a way to run these test asynchronously so the browser can stay alive between runs:

```
var benchmark = function(times, resultCallback) {
    var start, cum = 0, i = 0;

    function runOnce() {
         if (i++ < times) {
             start = new Date();
             benchmark_code.call();
             cum += new Date() - start;
             setTimeout(runOnce, 0);
         } else {
             resultCallback(cum);
         }
    }
    try {
        runOnce();
    } catch(e) {
        return e;
    }
};
```

Comment: You might want to update the answer to include that JS runs on the UI thread - it's implied in the answer but people who don't know that might not get it

Comment: I tried this, but the results is incorrect. I think it is because setTimeout will make the function run asynchronously.

Comment: @anlai - You would have to change the way the loop works to work asychronously.  I added an example to my answer.